# Is there a positive version of "tempt"?

Tags: antonyms, semantics

The verb "to tempt" refers to enticing or influencing somebody to do something, with strong connotations of that thing being something wrong, something they should not do.  But when I think about it, I can't come up with any word that specifically means to entice or influence somebody to do something *good.*  Probably the closest I can come up with is "inspire," but that doesn't quite feel like the concept I'm looking for.

Do we have a good word for "positive temptation" in English?

Comment: You tempt someone to do something pleasant - it doesn't _have_ to be wrong!  'Encourage' might be a possibility.

Comment: 'Coax', but like Kate I think this is basic.

Comment: It would obviously be a ***positive*** usage if you were trying to ***tempt*** your terminally anorexic daughter to eat something.

Comment: "to motivate" = to cause someone to behave in a particular way - cambridge.org - https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/motivate